# JavaScript: How to get comma separated string from json string?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON string value that corresponds to this object:

```
{
"id" : "122223232244",
"title" : "התרעת פיקוד העורף",
"data" : ["עוטף עזה 218","עוטף עזה 217"]
}
```

I am trying to extract the following value from the object above, so that the `data` array is joined together as a single comma separated string like this:

`"עוטף עזה 218,עוטף עזה 217"`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved via the [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method which is built into the `Array` type:

```js
const object = {
"id" : "122223232244",
"title" : "התרעת פיקוד העורף",
"data" : ["עוטף עזה 218","עוטף עזה 217"]
}

/* Join elements of data array in object to a comma separated string */
const value = object.data.join();

console.log(value);
```

If no `separator` argument is supplied, then the `join()` method will default to use a comma separator by default.

#### Update

If the JSON was supplied in raw text via a string you can use the [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method to extract an object from the JSON string value as a first step like so:

```js
const json = `{"id" : "122223232244","title" : "התרעת פיקוד העורף","data" : ["עוטף עזה 218","עוטף עזה 217"]}`

/* Parse input JSON string */
const object = JSON.parse(json);

/* Join elements of data array in object to a comma separated string */
const value = object.data.join();

console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Access object properties using dot notation (e.g. `obj.data`) and then on the array you can use `join` to convert to a string with a comma in between.

```js
const obj = {
    "id" : "122223232244",
    "title" : "התרעת פיקוד העורף",
    "data" : ["עוטף עזה 218","עוטף עזה 217"]
}

console.log(obj.data.join(', '))
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be accessible with the name of the object and dot notation:

```
let obj = {
  "id" : "122223232244",
  "title" : "התרעת פיקוד העורף",
  "data" : ["עוטף עזה 218","עוטף עזה 217"]
}
```

You could get this with:

```
obj.data
```

Comment: I edited the code to be clearer above.  

Dot notation uses the name of the object followed by a dot, followed by the name of the property you are trying to get.

You can save obj.data to a variable like this:

      let data = obj.data;

Comment: You're welcome.  Here is the documentation for how this sort of thing works:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Syntax